# Pr(Z>|z|) values and the level of significance

Tags: r, regression

If your logistic regression fit has coefficients with the following attributes, do you look at the values of `Pr(Z>|z|)` are smaller than 0.95 to determine whether that variable is needed at a 5% level of significance?

ie. If `Pr(>|z|)` is 0.964, this variable is not needed at 5% significance.

[image]

Comment: How much faith would you put in an estimate ($-14.3$) whose standard error ($314$) is over 20 times greater than the estimate itself?

Comment: Is it really $P(Z \geq |z|)$ that you want or did you mean $P(|Z| \geq z)$?

Comment: The p values in regression do not tell you if a variable is "needed".

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, the p-value given for the Z-statistic would have to be interpreted as how likely it is that a result as extreme or more extreme than that observed would have occured under the null hypothesis. I.e. 0.96 would in principle mean that the data are providing very little evidence that the variable is needed (while small values such as, say, $p\leq 0.05$ would provide evidence for the likely relevance of the variable, as pointed out by others already). However, a lack of clear evidence that the variable is needed in the model to explain the this particular data set would not imply evidence that the variable is not needed. That would require a difference approach and with a very larege standard error one would not normally be able to say that the variable does not have an effect. Also, it is a very bad idea to decide which variables are to be included in a model based on p-values and then fitting the model with or without them as if no model selection had occurred.

Secondly, as also pointed out by others, when you get this huge a coefficient (corresponds to an odds ratio of $e^{-14.29}$) and standard error from logistic regression, you typically have some problem. E.g. the algorithm did not converge or there is complete separation in the data. If your model really did only include an intercept, then perhaps there are no events at all, and all records did not have an outcome? If so, then a standard logistic regression may not be able to tell you a lot. There are some alternatives for such sparse data situations (e.g. a Bayesian analysis including the available prior information).

Answer (score 2):

You are using the normal approximation and specifically the Wald test so you do what you would do in a regular t-test. That is, you reject the null hypothesis if the probability of the event $\left\{Z \geq |z| \right\}$ is lower than the conventional threshold of $0.05$. Alternatively you fail to reject the null hypothesis if your p-value is not small enough.

Comment: Am i correct to say that the null hypothesis is rejected (`intecept` is significant) at 10% significance level if `Pr(Z>|z|)` has values larger than 0.90?

Comment: @Nyxynyx But if you want to use a (two-tailed) size 0.1 test, you only reject for p-values lower than 0.1, So no, it's not.

Comment: How do you justify a t-test rather than a z-test? (e.g. what would make the distribution nearer to a t rather than a z -- which at least has an asymptotic justification)

Comment: @Glen_b That needed clarifying on my part. I am only suggesting the t-test becase it is more consevative (higher critical values) as it is often the case that the approximate normality does not hold for the Wald ratio. Of course, in the limit the difference is negligible.

Comment: With logistic regression, as here, when the distribution is non-normal, is there any reason to believe the t will be better than the normal? Or in those cases does the normal tend to be conservative?

Comment: @Glen_b I am sorry, I missed your comment. The t-distribution will certainly not provide a better fit but in view of the possible non-normality, its greater critical values will provide longer CIs and more conservative tests. I've always thought of it as a more robust alternative but this is solely a  personal preference of course.

Answer (score 2):

The value of the coefficient and its large standard error suggest that what we are seeing here is separation or the Hauck-Donner effect which has its own tag [hauck-donner-effect](/questions/tagged/hauck-donner-effect) which has a clear and helpful wiki excerpt. I think therefore the debate about $t$ versus $z$ is a red herring. Profile likelihood would be the way to go or reformulating the problem.